# I am creating a simple website with 3 pages but i keep getting an erro. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HomePage'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, debugging, virtualenv

```
I cannot figure out why I keep getting the ModuleNotFoundError: 
No module named 'HomePage' error I'm fairly new to Django but 
have spent a majority of the day trying to figure out how to 
make a homepage where I could link a Homepage.html and have a 
different page on my original page. Any help would be 
appreciated this is my second question ever on here please be 
gentle.

    Below is the full error am getting.

        PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\InstitutionFinderWebsite> 
        python 
        manage.py runserver;      
        Watching for file changes with StatReloader
        Exception in thread django-main-thread:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\python\python3.10.0\lib\threading.py", line 
       1009, in 
        _bootstrap_inner     
        self.run()
        File "C:\python\python3.10.0\lib\threading.py", line 
946, in 
        run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        File 
"C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite- 
       jRRQ2QPD\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", 
line 64, 
        in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File 
"C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite- 
       jRRQ2QPD\lib\site- 
       packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", 
line 115, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
        File 
 "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite- 
       jRRQ2QPD\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception raise _exception[1]
          
File"C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite- 
       jRRQ2QPD\lib\site-
```

packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py",
line 381, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File
"C:\Users\admin.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite-
jRRQ2QPD\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
File
"C:\Users\admin.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite-
jRRQ2QPD\lib\site-packages\django_*init*_.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\admin.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite-
jRRQ2QPD\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File
"C:\Users\admin.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite-
jRRQ2QPD\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 223, in
create
import_module(entry)
File "C:\python\python3.10.0\lib\importlib_*init*_.py", line
126, in import_module    return
_bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1050, in
_gcd_import
File "", line 1027, in
_find_and_load
File "", line 992, in
_find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 241, in
_call_with_frames_removed
File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1027, in
_find_and_load
File "", line 1004, in
_find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HomePage'

```
    The error seem to be pointing on the 2 files below, but i dont 
    know how to edit them.

     File "C:\python\python3.10.0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 
     126, in import_module    return

     File "C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\InstitutionFinderWebsite- 
     jRRQ2QPD\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 223, 
     in create 
     
     msg = "Module '%s' does not contain a '%s' class." % (mod_path, cls_name)
                if candidates:
                    msg += ' Choices are: %s.' % ', '.join(candidates)
                raise ImportError(msg)
            else:
                # Re-trigger the module import exception.
                import_module(entry) - "this is where line 223 is 
    on the config.py file"

    These are my settings.
    
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'HomePage.html',
    'PrivateSchools',
    'PublicSchools',
    ]   

    MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'InstitutionFinderWebsite.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 
    'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    ]
    
    These are the codes for my Home page.

    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Institution Finder Website<title>
                <h1><b>Institution Finder Website</b></h1>>
                <p>
                <h1><b>List of Schools</b></h1>
                </p>
        </head>
        <bodybgcolor="#837E7C" text="#FFA500">
            <form action="", method="get">
                (% csrf-token %)
                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Serch 
    Blog" >
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <p>
                <b><h2>Public Schools</h2></b>
                <a href={ % url 'PublicSchools' %} >Public 
    Schools</a>
                <li> Maseno University</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Maseno 
    uni.JPG">
                <li>JKUAT University</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\jkuat.JPG">
                <li>Moi University</li>
                </p>
                
                <p>
                <b><h3>Private Schools</h3></b>
                <li>Dayster University</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\dayster.JPG">
                <li>Pioneer University</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\pioneer.JPG">
                <li>USIU</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\usiu.JPG">
                </p>
        </body>
    </html>

These are the codes for the Private schools page
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Institution Finder Website<title>
                <h1><b>Institution Finder Website</b></h1>>
                <p>
                <h1><b>Private Schools</b></h1>
                </p>
        </head>
        <bodybgcolor="#837E7C" text="#FFA500">
                
                <p>
                <b><h3>Private Schools</h3></b>
                <a href= {% url 'HomePage.html' %} >Home Page</a>
                <li>Dayster University</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\dayster.JPG">
                <li>Pioneer University</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\pioneer.JPG">
                <li>USIU</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\usiu.JPG">
                </p>
        </body>
    </html>

This are the codes for the Public schools page.

    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Institution Finder Website<title>
                <h1><b>Institution Finder Website</b></h1>>
                <p>
                <h1><b>Public Schools</b></h1>
                </p>
        </head>
        <bodybgcolor="#837E7C" text="#FFA500">
            <p>
                <b><h2>Public Schools</h2></b>
                <a href={% url'PrivateSchools' %}>Private 
    Schools</a>
                <li> Maseno University</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Maseno 
    uni.JPG">
                <li>JKUAT University</li>
                <IMG  src="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\jkuat.JPG">
                <li>Moi University</li>
                </p>
                
        </body>
    </html>

   Below is the photo is the structure of my project

   [enter image description here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ2QX.png
```

Comment: remove HomePage.html from INSTALLED_APPS. in INSTALLED_APPS you place the apps that you create from ```python manage.py startapp appname```

Answer (score 0):

Update the below `INSTALLED_APPS`  in your settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'PrivateSchools',
    'PublicSchools',
    ]
```

Just remove the `HomePage.html` from the list. INSTALLED_APPS should only contain the app name.